# Hosting a wordpress blog in a Laravel application

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel

I currently have a Laravel application deployed in a autoscaling group at `www.example.com` and a wordpress blog at `blog.example.com` on a single instance.

I have been asked to move the blog to `example.com/blog`.

I don't want to merge the code bases and the blog does not need to be in the autoscaling group.

I tried to use rewrite rules to rewrite `example.com/xxx` to `blog.example.com` without affecting the url in the browser but I can only get it to redirect ending up with `blog.example.com/xxx` in the address bar.

What is the best way to achieve having `example.com/blog/xxx` as a valid url while allowing me to host the Wordpress installation far far far away from my Laravel app?

This was my attempt at url rewriting which didn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog(.*)?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this **before** Laravel rules:

```
RewriteRule ^blog - [L,NC]
```

This will let you use Wordpress with Laravel.

Also, you could try [this solution](http://www.cesarserna.com/htaccess-rewrite-rules-laravel-lumen-wordpress/).