# Laravel 5.1 on apache2 wont to start

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5.1, virtualhost

Iadd laravel files into folder `/var/www/html/laravel3`
after that I change apache2.conf file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel3
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
...
```

but when I try http://mywebsite.com I get:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /auth/login was not found on this server.

Also I delete .htaccess file from /laravel3 folder

What to do now?

in apache2 I have:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in sites-available/laravel.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName bedbids.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel3/public"
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel3/public">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not remove the `.htaccess` file, it rewrites requests to the `index.php`.

For your apache config, the `DocumentRoot` should point to the public directory and you should  set `AllowOverride All`, otherwise the htaccess is ignored.

This should work for you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel3/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel3/public/>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ...
```

After that change, restart apache and it should be up and running.

Comment: WHen i write AllowOverride All then nothing work I GET ERROR 500.... so before that index.html in public folder workbut now dont work... also my problem is index.php

Comment: What does your apache error log say? And btw, Order, Allow and Deny access controls are deprecated, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: [Thu May 12 08:43:53.830932 2016] [core:error] [pid 26135] [client 109.92.214.150:28764] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://40.68.126.190/auth/login

Comment: If you edit index.php and put a `die('here');` at the top, does it display?

Comment: With the same error message? And did you put the die at the top? Above the `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` ?

Comment: NOW I GET 'here' at browser screen

Comment: You should use the default .htaccess in the public folder as provided by laravel. In your case: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/public/.htaccess.

Comment: Do you have code in place that redirects visitors from and to the login page? My guess is that you redirect non-logged in users to the login page and redirect them back to a non-public page from there? But that's another issue

Comment: yes i redirect them, its no problem, work in my localhost

Answer (score 0):

You should point Apache to a `public` directory inside Laravel root, for example:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel3/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/laravel3/public">
```

Also, you shouldn't edit or delete `.htaccess`.

After you made these changes, do not forget to reboot Apache.

**Update**

Original `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exactly don't work? You're getting an error? If yes, what error? What is the real path for a `public` directory? If you want to get help, you need to provide information.

Comment: I get: Not Found

The requested URL /auth/login was not found on this server. when I try to go to my domain in browser ... real path for public is /var/www/html/laravel3/public

Comment: Did you reboot web server? Also, try `http://mywebsite.com` first (without `auth/login`), does it work?

Comment: its interesting situation, now I put index.html file in public folder and that index file works but when I delete it index.php wont work...

Comment: also I think that my laravel route dont work... when I point something in public folder... some .js file work but when I try to point /auth/login dont work

Comment: So, the problem is Apache doesn't run `/public/index.php`. Did you return original `.htaccess` back to a public directory? If you did and still root page doesn't work, please update your question with Apache config.

Comment: Looks fine. So, did you return original `.htaccess` to a `public` directory? It really feels like you have edit this file or deleted it.

Comment: i return .htaccess to public and also i have .htaccess to root folder

Comment: Delete one from the root. Also, is PHP enabled in Apache?

Comment: yes offcource php is enabled ... phpmyadmin works great

Comment: I've updated my post with original `.htaccess`. Put it in a `public` directory. You've posted your `.htaccess` and it's not the working one.

Comment: again i have: Not Found

The requested URL /forhotelier was not found on this server.

Comment: root send me to folder /wordpress into public folder so yes it works but etc. /auth/login dont work - return me 404 error not found

Comment: Well, it's not a normal. When you're goint to `/`, you should see Laravel start page, but not Wordpress or something. Why didn't you tell you're trying to use both Wordpress and Laravel in the same directory? Please look my answer here for solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796293/hosting-a-wordpress-blog-in-a-laravel-application

Comment: no laravel is just here core app and wordpress is just for landing page... so when user tupe domain.com/ I show them wordpress page ... and just in that case... other when user go /auth/login then must go to login page

Comment: can we have TeamViewer seasson just 2 min ?