# Laravel Project on Existing Website

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to the Laravel framework.  I am considering learning it and using it for a personal project, but as I am reading through the documentation I see that the web server document root would need to be set to the project folder.

Is it possible to integrate a laravel project with an existing webiste built with PHP and apache?  For example, if I have a wordpresss install and wasn't using a framework but wanted tp create a subsite, I could just add more html and php files into a folder somewhere on the existing site or use a different vhost. Not sure if integrating would be so easy with Laravel,though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. The [solution](http://www.cesarserna.com/htaccess-rewrite-rules-laravel-lumen-wordpress/) I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796293/hosting-a-wordpress-blog-in-a-laravel-application) should work for you.

To make it work you should modify both Laravel and Wordpress `.htaccess` files.

Laravel `.htaccess` example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        #Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ # <=== NEW LINE!!!!

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Wordpress `.htaccess` example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/   # <==== CHANGED LINE!!
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L] # <==== CHANGED LINE!!!
</IfModule>
```